# Unir los resulatdos de 2 filas en una sola

Tags: php, mysql

esta es mi consulta

```
$sql="select a.id_certf_cab,a.Fec_Creacion,a.Nro_Certf, CONCAT(Nombre,Ape_pat,Ape_mat) nombres,
        a.tipo_trans, c.descripcion_certificado,a.precio,d.Sucursal,e.Usuario,f.Valor,f.id_atributos
        from tbl_certf_cab a inner join tbl_certf_det f
        on a.id_certf_cab=f.id_certf_cab inner join tbl_cliente b
        on a.id_cliente=b.id_cliente inner join tbl_tipocertificado c
        on a.id_certificado=c.id_certificado inner join tbl_sucursal d
        on a.id_sucursal=d.ID_SUCURSAL inner join tbl_usuario e
        on a.User_Creacion=e.ID_USUARIO 
        WHERE f.id_atributos in(18,7) and a.Fec_Modificacion between '".$var_txt_finicio."' and '".$var_txt_ffinal."'group by f.Valor order by a.Nro_Certf asc";
```

y me muetra el resultado con el mismo 12314 en dos lineas

```
98  2023-09-06 00:00:00 12314       C0C-921 M. INCORP.
99  2023-09-06 00:00:00 12314   KNCSD211227837259       M. INCORP.
```

Comment: Muestra como se deberia ver el resultado que esperas

Comment: La pregunta no es de php sino de SQL. Deberías poner la estructura básica de las tablas y una somera explicación de qué representan y qué quieres conseguir exactamente. El GROUP BY no creo que te sirva de mucho si no hay ninguna función de acumulación en los elementos seleccionados.

Comment: Debes poner la columna por la que quieres agrupar dentro del `GROUP BY`, si dicha columna es `a.Nro_Certf`, entonces, intenta poner la consulta así: **`... group by f.Valor, a.Nro_Certf ...`**

Comment: ¿Es MariaDB/MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL...?